# make text file by repeating word based on frequency

Tags: python, parsing, text, frequency, cpu-word

I aware this question could inappropriate based on stackoverflow question criteria, but I have been doing coding practices couple months for parsing and analyzing texts which I never done programming before, and had help from this forum.

I have analyzed multiple xml files with frequency analysis, stored in mysqldb.
[word, count]

I would like to make a text file just by repeating words based on the frequency. (ex. breakfast, 6 => breakfast breakfast breakfast breakfast breakfast breakfast)
including one space between repeating words, and parse words from the lowest (the beginning of the text) to the highest frequency ('a' or 'the' will be the most frequent segment, and comes to the last part of the text content).

Please allow me to get some idea, library, coding example..
Thank you.

```
import math
import random
import requests
import collections
import string
import re
import MySQLdb as mdb
import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET
from xml.dom import minidom
from string import punctuation
from oauthlib import *
from operator import itemgetter
from collections import defaultdict
from functools import reduce
import requests, re
from xml.etree import ElementTree
from collections import Counter
from lxml import html




### MYSQL ###

db = mdb.connect(host="****", user="****", passwd="****", db="****")

cursor = db.cursor()
sql = "DROP TABLE IF EXISTS Table1"
cursor.execute(sql)
db.commit()
sql = "CREATE TABLE Table1(Id INT PRIMARY KEY AUTO_INCREMENT, keyword TEXT, frequency INT)"
cursor.execute(sql)
db.commit()



## XML PARSING
def main(n=1000):

    # A list of feeds to process and their xpath


    feeds = [
        {'url': 'http://www.nyartbeat.com/list/event_type_print_painting.en.xml', 'xpath': './/Description'},
        {'url': 'http://feeds.feedburner.com/FriezeMagazineUniversal?format=xml', 'xpath': './/description'},
        {'url': 'http://www.artandeducation.net/category/announcement/feed/', 'xpath': './/description'},
        {'url': 'http://www.blouinartinfo.com/rss/visual-arts.xml', 'xpath': './/description'},
        {'url': 'http://feeds.feedburner.com/ContemporaryArtDaily?format=xml', 'xpath': './/description'}
    ]



    # A place to hold all feed results
    results = []

    # Loop all the feeds
    for feed in feeds:
        # Append feed results together
        results = results + process(feed['url'], feed['xpath'])

    # Join all results into a big string
    contents=",".join(map(str, results))

    # Remove double+ spaces
    contents = re.sub('\s+', ' ', contents)

    # Remove everything that is not a character or whitespace
    contents = re.sub('[^A-Za-z ]+', '', contents)

    # Create a list of lower case words that are at least 8 characters
    words=[w.lower() for w in contents.split() if len(w) >=1 ]


    # Count the words
    word_count = Counter(words)

    # Clean the content a little
    filter_words = ['art', 'artist', 'artist']
    for word in filter_words:
        if word in word_count:
            del word_count[word]



# Add to DB
    for word, count in word_count.most_common(n):
                sql = """INSERT INTO Table1 (keyword, frequency) VALUES(%s, %s)"""
                cursor.execute(sql, (word, count))
                db.commit()

def process(url, xpath):
    """
    Downloads a feed url and extracts the results with a variable path
    :param url: string
    :param xpath: string
    :return: list
    """
    contents = requests.get(url)
    root = ElementTree.fromstring(contents.content)
    return [element.text.encode('utf8') if element.text is not None else '' for element in root.findall(xpath)]





if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because this is neither a code-writing nor tutorial service

Comment: I will add a code that I have parsed and analyzed xmls

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming `word_count.most_common(n)` that you used in the for loop will return a tuple or a list with `word` and `count` in that order:

Lets store it in a variable:

```
words = word_count.most_common(n)
# Ex: [('a',5),('apples',2),('the',4)]
```

Using itemgetter, sort it by the count:

```
from operator import itemgetter
words = sorted(words, key = itemgetter(1))
# words = [('apples', 2), ('the', 4), ('a', 5)]
```

Now go through each entry, and append it to a list:

```
out = []
for word, count in words:
    out += [word]*count
# out = ['apples', 'apples', 'the', 'the', 'the', 'the', 'a', 'a', 'a', 'a', 'a']
```

The following line will make it into a long string:

```
final = " ".join(out)
# final = "apples apples the the the the a a a a a"
```

Now just write it to a file:

```
with open("filename.txt","w+") as f:
    f.write(final)
```

The code would look like this:

```
from operator import itemgetter

words = word_count.most_common(n)
words = sorted(words, key = itemgetter(1))

out = []
for word, count in words:
    out += [word]*count

final = " ".join(out)

with open("filename.txt","w+") as f:
    f.write(final)
```

Comment: Thank you so much Electron!